# Riccati-type ODE: time-dependent coefficients, analytical solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider this Riccati-type ODE:

$$
F'(t)=\frac{1}{10}+F(t) \left(F(t)+i \cos (10 t)-\frac{1}{5}\right),
$$
$$
F(0)=0
$$

For relatively small t range, e.g. $[0,1]$, one may numerically solve it. However, for larger ranges, e.g. $t\in[0,30]$, numerical solutions become very unstable and either diverges or gives many "spikes" that resemble the $\tan(..)$ function. (real part of F plotted below).

For this Riccati ODE, I cannot guess a particular solution. Moreover, if the coefficients are time-independent $F'(t)=a+b F(t)+c F(t)^2$ the solution is rather straightforward; here, due to the $\cos(10t)$ term, an analytical solution seems rather difficult. What might be a good approach to solve this problem? (maybe either eliminate cos(...) or convert to $h'(t)=h(t)*[h(t)+g(t)]$, i.e. Bernoulli-type ODEs)

[image]

Comment: Hi. Since this is an ODE, may I ask what's the point of having $F[\cdot]$ and $F(\cdot)$ as different expressions ?

Comment: @Rebellos Sorry, copy-paste from Mathematica. Now changed all $F[\cdot]$ to $F(\cdot)$

Answer (score 1):

Do not solve this directly, but use the usual parametrization by the solution of a second order linear ODE, that is, $F=-\frac{G'}{G}$ where
$$
0=G''(t)+(\tfrac15-i\cos(10t))G'(t)+\tfrac1{10}G(t),~~G(0)=1,~G'(0)=0.
$$
As this ODE has continuous and bounded coefficients, its solution will be tame. Roots of $G$, if there are any, are poles of $F$. In the computed solution, roots of the real part of $G$ have a small and decreasing positive imaginary part, so that $F$ has nearly poles at these positions.

[image]

```
def ODEfunc(t,u): return [ u[1], -0.1*u[0]-(0.2-1j*np.cos(10*t))*u[1] ];
t = np.arange(0,30.01,0.02);
res = solve_ivp(ODEfunc, [t[0], t[-1]], [1+0j,0j], t_eval=t)

G = res.y[0];
F = -res.y[1]/res.y[0];
plt.subplot(211); plt.plot(t,G.real,t,G.imag); plt.legend(["G.real", "G.imag"]); plt.grid()
plt.subplot(212); plt.plot(t,F.real,t,F.imag); plt.legend(["F.real", "F.imag"]); plt.ylim(-20,20); plt.grid()
plt.show()
```